# Calling methods from inheriting classes

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, methods

```
abstract class Person
{
    public abstract void LoadName(string name);
}

class Soldier : Person
{
    string soldierName;
    int ID;

    public override void LoadName(string name)
    {
        soldierName = name;
    }

    public void LoadName(int id)
    {
        ID = id;
    }
}

class PersonManager
{
    public void LoadNames(Person[] person, string[] names, int[] id)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < p.Length; i++)
        {
            person[i].LoadName(names[i]);

            if(person[i] is Soldier)
            {
                /* What I want to do:
                person.LoadName(id[someValue]);       
                   -> Cannot convert from 'string' to 'int'

                   or:
                (Soldier)person.LoadName(id[someValue]);
                   -> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement and new object expressions can be used as a statement
                */

                // What I have to do:
                Soldier s = (Soldier)person[i];
                s.LoadName(id[someValue]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this?
My original class is a lot bigger, so copying it isn't ideal.

(Note that this example is in no relation to my project, so it might not be the best example.)

Comment: This question might be better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I would change `LoadName` to `SetName`. `LoadName` implies it will be getting the name, and therefore return a string.

Comment: why not including LoadName with id into abstract class and override both?

Comment: @sstan It could have been, except that this seems to be a bit exampl-ish. This question would be very borderline on Code Review, with high probability to be closed, or OP would likely not be happy with the answers on CR. I'd recommend reading [A Guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users) if you haven't done so already.

Comment: It strikes me as odd that you have person objects that are not "loaded" in the first place. Why not have a constructor that takes id and name and do creation and initialisation at once, the moment you have your input data and know what type to create? This could be the base type constructor. If you need more (data) for derived types, create additional constructors in the derived types and call the base constructor from them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can say:

```
((Soldier)person[i]).LoadName(id[someValue]);
```

Which isn't that bad. The problem here is that person doesn't have a `LoadName(int)` Of course, creating an abstract overload in the parent class would fix this problem, but I'm assuming you don't want to do that. Therefore, `LoadName(int)` is unique to the `Soldier` class and this is the only way to get it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way

```
    abstract class Person
    {
        public abstract void LoadName(string name);
    }

    class Soldier : Person
    {
        public string soldierName { get; set; }
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public override void LoadName(string name)
        {
            soldierName = name;
        }

        public void LoadName(int id)
        {
            ID = id;
        }
    }

    class PersonManager
    {
        public void LoadNames(Person[] person, string[] names, int[] id)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < p.Length; i++)
            {
                person[i].LoadName(names[i]);

                if (person[i] is Soldier)
                {
                    Person newPerson = new Soldier() { soldierName = names[i], ID = id[i] }; 
                }
            }
        }
    }
​
```

Or this

```
    abstract class Person
    {
        public abstract void LoadName(string name, int id);
    }

    class Soldier : Person
    {
        public string soldierName { get; set; }
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public override void LoadName(string name, int id)
        {
            soldierName = name;
            ID = id;
        }

    }

    class PersonManager
    {
        public void LoadNames(Person[] person, string[] names, int[] id)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < p.Length; i++)
            {

                if (person[i] is Soldier)
                {
                    person[i].LoadName(names[i], id[i]); 
                }
            }
        }
    }
​
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way that simplifies the design and makes the code more natural is to add the overload to the `Person` abstract class itself. This forces any inheriting class to provide an implementation for LoadName(int id), which I think it is healthy, as id is more suited for identifying an entity.

```
abstract class Person
{
    public abstract void LoadName(string name);
    public abstract void LoadName(int id);
}

class Soldier : Person
{
    string soldierName;
    int ID;

    public override void LoadName(string name)
    {
        soldierName = name;
    }

    public override void LoadName(int id)
    {
        ID = id;
    }
}

class PersonManager
{
    public void LoadNames(Person[] person, string[] names, int[] id)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < person.Length; i++)
        {
            person[i].LoadName(names[i]);
            person[i].LoadName(id[i]);
        }
    }
}
```